# Sending emails in parallel at a particular frequency

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to send 5 emails in parallel. The function *scheduleEmails* takes a list of list of 5 email addresses as an input. My code looks like as follows:

```
import multiprocessing
import smtplib

def sendMail(email):
    #sends email using smtplib
    # returns True in case of success, False in case of failure

def scheduleEmails(emailLst):
    """
    emailLst is a list of list of 5 emails
    emailLst = [[emailAddr1,emailAddr2,emailAddr3...emailAddr5],
                [emailAddr6...emailAddr10],
                [emailAddr11... emailAddr[15],...]
    """
    FREQUENCY = 5 # no. of emails to be send per second
    for i in range(len(emailLst)):
            p = multiprocessing.Pool(FREQUENCY)
            emails = emailLst[i]
            results = p.map(sendEmail,emails)

 scheduleEmails(someEmailLst)
```

The code works well but after some time, it hangs. Can you point out the mistake or suggest a better way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How many subprocesses do you have spawned after 'a while'? To be sure not to spam your system with zillions of subprocesses, explicitly [close](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.close) the multiprocessing pool after collecting the results. Also, I do not see any logic in you code that controls the actual `frequency` of sending emails. Consider you have 1000 lists of 5 emails in your `emailLst`. Your loop will spawn 1000 multiprocessing pools, i.e. 5000 subprocesses, as fast as it can. You need to implement some timing/scheduling code. In the simplest case this would be a `time.sleep(1)` in your loop.

Also, multiproecessing is not really appropriate for this problem, because sending mails is not CPU bound. It's even not I/O bound in your case I guess. You could consider `threading` for the purpose of outsourcing a blocking call to a thread instead of a subprocesses.